# Rails 3.2.3 - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been following along with the updated version of Michael Hartl's ["Ruby on Rails Tutorial"](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#fig%3aheroku_app_31) and I encountered an error at the "git push heroku master" step.  The error produced by the GIT bash is as follows:

```
 $git push heroku master
 Counting objects: 70, done

 ...

 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........

 Bundler could not find compatible version for gem "railties":
 In Gemfile:
 rails (= 3.2.3) ruby depends on
 railties (= 3.2.3) ruby
 jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
 railties (3.2.4.rc1)
```

Also, here is the Gemfile I used:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead:
    # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

    group :development do
      gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    end


    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

      # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
      # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

      gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

    # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

    # To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
    # gem 'jbuilder'

    # Use unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Deploy with Capistrano
    # gem 'capistrano'

    # To use debugger
    # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

The only debugging instructions I could find dealt with versions of Ruby that were different than the version used in the tutorial (that is, versions that weren't 3.2.3), so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your Gemfile please

Comment: Sorry about that... I added my Gemfile above.

Comment: Just as info: the tutorial worked about a month ago. Something in the dependencies changed since then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the output:

```
jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
railties (3.2.4.rc1)
```

The **jquery-rails** gem you're using relies on a different rails version than you do. You should either change the **jquery-rails** dependency or upgrade Rails.

**UPDATE**

Looks like you might have found a bug in **bundler**. So, to get it working, you will have to change your Rails version to:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.4.rc1'
```

Comment: How would you recommend I change the jquery-rails dependency?  The tutorial [specifically recommends v2.0.0](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#code:gemfile_sqlite_version) and I'm a complete novice to Ruby on Rails, so I'm lost!

Comment: I updated the Gemfile and ran a bundle update, but I'm still getting the same error when I try to push to Heroku.  Is there  step in the procedure that I'm missing?  Sorry for all the questions, but I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you commiting the file? Delete your Gemfile.lock, run bundle install again, commit then push to heroku.

Comment: This is actually a bug in the jquery-rails 2.0.0 gem. See the [discussion at GitHub](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/issues/62). The fix is to use a newer version of jquery-rails, which you can find in the [permanent Rails Tutorial Gemfile](http://railstutorial.org/gemfile). I've updated the tutorial accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug in the jquery-rails 2.0.0 gem. See the [discussion at GitHub](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/issues/62). The fix is to use a newer version of jquery-rails, which you can find in the [permanent Rails Tutorial Gemfile](http://railstutorial.org/gemfile). I've updated the tutorial accordingly.

Comment: Note this problem also applies to the very first gems/rails setup instructions in chapter 1.2.4. Just changing that one dependency to 2.0.2 fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line in the Gemfile that said **gem 'rails', '3.2.3'** to **gem 'rails', '3.2.5'**, and it ran for a long time, finally stopping because it doesn't have **libpq-fe.h** (I think I've found it and will try again).  Of course, this fix may require that you have Rails 3.2.5 installed, I don't know (maybe bundle installs it?)