# Can’t run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I’m working on getting my first rails application, but for whatever reason, when I run the command `$rails server`, my terminal throws back this error:

```
/Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:161:in `start'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `block in resolve'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/Toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

I can’t find anything here on Stack Overflow. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792522/rails-3-2-3-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-railties

Comment: Also it's a small point but if you are using RoR 3.2 + you can just use `rails s` as the command to start the server. Also if you do `rails s -d` you can use the current terminal and to shut it down you can run `ps -auxx | grep 'ruby'` and then `kill -2 <PID of server process>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the required gems that are used by Rails when started. Before you run `rails s` be sure to run `bundle install` or `bundle update`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Gemfile has a line that looks like: `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Then from your project's directory: `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

Because on Rubygems server, that version shows:

```
2.0.0 December 20, 2011 yanked
```